# VBA object argument mismatch type

Tags: vba, object, types, arguments, mismatch

I've created a code that use a subroutine into another subroutine in VBA.
Specifically, I pass an argument returned by two method: Documents.Add and Selection.
Unfortunately I receive a mismatch errore beetween argument.
This is the code:

```
Sub crea_tabella(data As String, argomento As String, i As Integer, objDoc As Object, objSelection As Object)
    objSelection.TypeText "Table 1"
    objSelection.TypeParagraph
    Set objRange = objSelection.Range
    objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 5, 5
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(i)
    objTable.Borders.Enable = True
    
    objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = data
    objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = argomento
    
    selezione.EndKey 6
    selezione.TypeParagraph
End Sub
Sub crea_tabelle_multiple()
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    Call crea_tabella("01/01/2021", "Primo argomento", 1, objDoc, objSelection)
End Sub
```

Please.... Someone help me...

Comment: Please add Option Explicit at the start of your code.  This will show you that you have a number of variables that you did not dim.  When you have done this please tell us the line at which you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the type name of objDoc and objSelection and I put them in the code:

```
Sub crea_tabella(data As String, argomento As String, i As Integer, objDoc As Document, objSelection As Selection)
    objSelection.TypeText "Table 1"
    objSelection.TypeParagraph
    Set objRange = objSelection.Range
    objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 5, 5
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(i)
    objTable.Borders.Enable = True
    
    objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = data
    objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = argomento
    
    selezione.EndKey 6
    selezione.TypeParagraph
End Sub
Sub crea_tabelle_multiple()
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    'MsgBox TypeName(objDoc)
    'MsgBox TypeName(objSelection)
    Call crea_tabella("01/01/2021", "Primo argomento", 1, objDoc, objSelection)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the error is stilly present

Answer (score 0):

objDoc and objSelection were not declared in crea_tabelle_multiple(), so they are of Variant type. They cannot be passed ByRef in crea_tabella(), because the corresponding arguments objDoc As Document, objSelection As Selection have the exact data type - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch.

Add an explicit type definition for objDoc and objSelection in crea_tabelle_multiple():

```
Sub crea_tabelle_multiple()
    Dim objDoc As Document, objSelection As Selection ' add it

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
    'MsgBox TypeName(objDoc)
    'MsgBox TypeName(objSelection)
    Call crea_tabella("01/01/2021", "Primo argomento", 1, objDoc, objSelection)
End Sub
```